# jquery menu opacity fadeToggle

Tags: jquery, submenu

I have a fadeToggle submenu but if the mouse is left hovering over the submenu, text from the underlying page ends up above it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('ul>li').stop().fadeToggle(800);


});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you create this scenario at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Here it is on jsfiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/weat/drud5xwr/
I have tried making the header z index high, but it makes no difference.

Comment: you can see the problem on the site here [link](http://quodvultdeus.com/ResourcesStMarks.html)[link]

Comment: I don't think it is about z-index. it seems like the opacity, somehow gets sets to something less than 1 when hovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, the issue was caused by the opacity. Most likely it was conflicting with some other css. I updated your sub `li` style to be like this:

```
ul li li {
    background:#999;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    display:none;   
    opacity:0.999;
}
```

And it appears to be working fine now. Here is the updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/drud5xwr/2/